# What does the exclamation mark mean here: "int16u!"?

Tags: .net, variables, integer

I am looking at [Exif Tags here](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) and came across some variable types I haven't seen before. I wonder specifically what the exclamation mark here mean: "int16u!"?

I understand that int16u means: unsigned integer.

Comment: Bear in mind `int16u` means **16 bit** unsigned integer (unsigned short).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [source](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html):

> An exclamation point (!) indicates a tag that is considered Unsafe to write under normal circumstances. These tags are not written unless specified explicitly (ie. not when wildcards or "all" are used), and care should be taken when editing them manually since they may affect the way an image is rendered.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I had seen that information before!

Comment: I'm glad to help!